# Generating satisfiable and non satisfiable formulas

Tags: algorithm, logic, theory, boolean-logic

I am working in a project in which I have to generate propositional formulas in form CNF to perform some tests; And I come across the following questions:

1. How to generate a random satisfiable formula ?
2. How to generate a random valid formula ?

For the second question I have an idea, for example we can generate a random formula `p` and then take the formula `p or not p` and then convert the resulting formula in CNF but the problem is that can we generate all valid formulas this way?

The allowed booleans operators here are : `or,and,not`

Thank you for your help

Comment: I like this question a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let `L` be the set of `k` literals `l1,l2,l3,...,lk` for prespecified `k`. Now given the set of literals we can generate CNF formulas from them.

I would suggest first choosing the number of clauses---i.e. the number of conjucted OR-expressions---, say `m`, and then `n_1`,`n_2`,...,`n_m`, where `n_i` is the number of OR-connected literals. You may choose these numbers at random, or you can have them as parameters to better control the size and structure of the formula.

For example, for `m=2` and `n1=2` and `n2=2` you'd have CNFs of the form  `(l1 OR l2) AND (l3 OR l4)` where `li`'s are chosen from `L` and are either negated or not.

Now that you know what the formula will look like, iterate through positions of the literals and for each position:

- choose a literal `l` from `L` uniformly at random;
- flip a fair coin to decide whether to negate the literal.

You end up with a "random" formula in CNF. You don't know whether it is satisfiable, however.

**Update** (April 5th 2016)**.** If you wanted to efficiently generate a *random* satisfiable CNF with given parameters `k`, `m`, and `ni`'s, you would have to be able to efficiently compute which formulas are satisfiable (thus implicitly solving the `3-SAT` problem). For this reason I believe there is no polynomial-time algorithm (unless **P**=**NP**) for generating *random* 3-CNF (so that each satisfiable 3-CNF with the given structure is equally likely). Because generating random 3-CNF is hard, so is generating CNF in general.

There are probably algorithms for generating a subset of satisfiable 3-CNF's, which might be good enough for practical purposes; the same goes for generating unsatisfiable instances.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your answer gives a construction of a random formula but it does not handle the satisfiability part or the validity, what I wanted to do is to generate satisfiable (or valid) random formula

Comment: Ops. Sorry. Will think about it.

Comment: thanks for your remarks, as you said there might be some algorithms for generating a subset of 3-CNFs, As I pointed out in the question  `p or not p` for random p is one of those subsets that are satisfiable but I don't know if there exists another ways of dealing with the problem

Comment: I will see if there are some other ideas